# Using discriminants to find order of extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Any hints on how to show $[G:H]^{2}=\frac{disc(H)}{disc(G)}$,where G,H are free abelian groups of rank n and $H\subset G\subset K$,where K is a number field?

Alternative formulation, how to relate $[R:Z[a]]$ and disc(R),disc(Z[a])?

thanks

Comment: Dear TKM, The question you posted here before editing (although abbreviated in context and notation) made sense (at least to an expert), whereas the current one doesn't.  Regards,

Comment: i made a mistake, is that better? The question is verbatim from Marcus.

Comment: Dear TKM, You may want to add that $n$ is the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$.  Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I assume that what you mean is something to this effect:

If $\mathcal{O}\subseteq\mathcal{O}'$ are orders of $K$ (for some number field $K$) then $[\mathcal{O}':\mathcal{O}]\text{disc}(\mathcal{O}')=\text{disc}(\mathcal{O})$. This follows immediately from the following theorem of algebra:

> **Theorem:** *Let $R$ be a PID, and $M$ a free-module of rank $n$. Suppose that $N\leqslant M$ is a free module of rank $n$. Then, there exists a basis $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ of $M$ and $r_1,\ldots,r_n\in R$ such that $\{r_1b_1,\ldots,r_nb_n\}$ is a basis for $N$.*

Do you see why? (Hint: what are the $r_i$?)